# Swift 2.1 - Internet Connection Reachability AlertController, 4G is not recognised

Tags: ios, swift, viewcontroller

the following code below checks if their is an internet connection and displays an AlertController displaying that their is no internet connection. When the device is connected to a 'Wifi' connection the AlertController does not appear thus recognising that the device is connected to the internet, however when I turn my 4G on and not the Wifi then the AlertController appears stating that their is no internet connection. How could this be fixed so that the 4G is recognised as a successful internet connection and does not display the AlertController?

Here is my Reachability class

```
import Foundation
import SystemConfiguration

public class ReachabilityNotification {

    class func isConnectedToNetwork() -> Bool {

        var zeroAddress = sockaddr_in(sin_len: 0, sin_family: 0, sin_port: 0, sin_addr: in_addr(s_addr: 0), sin_zero: (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0))
        zeroAddress.sin_len = UInt8(sizeofValue(zeroAddress))
        zeroAddress.sin_family = sa_family_t(AF_INET)

        let defaultRouteReachability = withUnsafePointer(&zeroAddress) {
            SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithAddress(kCFAllocatorDefault, UnsafePointer($0))
        }

        var flags: SCNetworkReachabilityFlags = SCNetworkReachabilityFlags(rawValue: 0)
        if SCNetworkReachabilityGetFlags(defaultRouteReachability!, &flags) == false {
            return false
        }

        let isReachable = flags == .Reachable
        let needsConnection = flags == .ConnectionRequired

        return isReachable && !needsConnection

    }
}
```

Here is my ViewController class

```
import UIKit
import Foundation

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)

        if Reachability.isConnectedToNetwork() == true {
            print("Internet connection OK")
        } else {
            print("Internet connection FAILED")

            let connectionAlert = UIAlertController(title: "No Internet Connection", message: "Make sure your device is connected to the internet.", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

            connectionAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .Default, handler: { [unowned self] (action: UIAlertAction!) in
                self.performSegueWithIdentifier("NoConnection", sender: self)
                }))

            presentViewController(connectionAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Take a look at http://github.com/ashleymills/Reachability.swift, this might give you some pointers